# How to update comment of a specific row in SQL table with WHERE clause when its empty?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a gridview of a SQL table. The first two columns automatically get selected and put into the grid when the webpage starts and a date is selected. The third column is a comment section where I'd like to let the user input comments themselves. I have a text box that they can enter comments in when they select a row, but I can get the column to update properly.

```
Run_DB_Script("update Log_Transfers set Comment = '" + tmpBox.Text + "' where '" + GridView1.Rows[Row] + "'", ref tmpErr);
```

The bracketed [Row] is a int that is set to the row number they put in.

It executes the code, but nothing is there after hitting update.

Comment: What's the primary key of the table?

Comment: Your query is directly concatenating user input and is easily exploitable for `sql injection`. I highly recommend you read up on it, [this for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iElrPcUPZnA) is worth your time!

Comment: [How does the SQL injection from the “Bobby Tables” XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/327083)

Comment: Use the debugger to see what `GridView1.Rows[Row]` evaluates to. It is not going to be something that can go into a WHERE clause and I would place a bet you are getting an exception. Think about how you would write a WHERE clause yourself and then make the code do that.... after fixing the sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a SQL statement using the input from a user is opening the door for a SQL Injection hack.  A better alternative is to use parameters.

```
// set up the sql command to run with parameter placeholders
//  parameters are prefixed with an @
var command_text = "update Log_Transfers set Comment = @comment where @grid_row";
// Define the two parameters
SqlParameter comment = new SqlParameter("@comment",tmpBox.Text);
SqlParameter grid_row = new SqlParameter("@grid_row", ....);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Text = command_text;

// Add the parameters to the command
cmd.Parameters.Add(comment);
cmd.Parameters.Add(grid_row);
cmd.Execute();
```

Comment: Best to declare data type explicitly, also C# uses double quotes `new SqlParameter("@comment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = tmpBox.Text;`